# Why does my value change before my setTimeout function is called in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is a minimal replicable code:

```
function print(num) {
   console.log(num)
}
```

...later in the code

```
var num = 5;
var count = 0;
while (num != 0) {
   setTimeout(function() {print(num);}, 1000 * count)
   num--;
   count++;
}
```

I want my output to be `5 4 3 2 1` but instead my output is `0 0 0 0 0`

Why is this?

Comment: because you pass the result of  `print()` to `setTimeout()` and not the function itself ...

Comment: @Sirko oops! I updated the question.

Comment: By the time your timeout function is called in the event loop, the value of num has hit 0. The function always references the actual num variable, its value is not copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function call to `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(print(num), 1000 * count)
```

you're **calling** your `print()` function and passing its return value. If you want `print()` to be called when the timer expires, you have to pass a function to call it:

```
setTimeout(function() { print(num); }, 1000 * count)
```

Comment: Yeah I am doing this. Sorry, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass in the value of num at the time through the setTimeout function, if you wish for the value at that point in time to be used

```
function print(num) {
   console.log(num)
}

var num = 5;
var count = 0;
while (num != 0) {
   setTimeout(print, 1000 * count, num);
   num--;
   count++;
}
```